# How can I avoid repeating a parameter in this React Hook Form form with shadcn/ui?

Tags: reactjs, react-hook-form, zod, radix-ui

I'm trying to create a reusable input field, but I don't know how to avoid repeating "control={form.control}". My problem is that "form" is defined in the "PracticeForm" component (as I need to declare it for the general form), not in "ItemInput", so I get an error:

**PracticeForm.tsx:**

```
import { useForm } from "react-hook-form";
import { Button } from "./ui/button";
import { Form } from "./ui/form";
import * as z from "zod";
import { zodResolver } from "@hookform/resolvers/zod";
import ItemInput from "./ItemInput";

const formSchema = z.object({
      username: z.string(),
      email: z.string()
      .email({
        message: "Please enter a valid email"
      })
    });
    
    const PracticeForm = () => {
      const form = useForm<z.infer<typeof formSchema>>({
        resolver: zodResolver(formSchema),
        defaultValues: {
          username: "",
          email: "email"
        },
      });
    
      function onSubmit(values: z.infer<typeof formSchema>) {
        console.log(values);
      }
    
      return (
        <div>
          <Form {...form}>
            <form
              onSubmit={form.handleSubmit(onSubmit)}
              className="flex flex-col w-52 gap-2"
            >
              <ItemInput name="username" placeholder={"Enter username"}/>
              <ItemInput name="email" placeholder={"Enter email"}/>
              <Button variant={"outline"} type="submit">
                Submit
              </Button>
            </form>
          </Form>
        </div>
      );
    };
    
    export default PracticeForm;
```

**ItemInput.tsx:**

```
import { FormControl, FormField, FormItem, FormMessage } from "./ui/form"
import { Input } from "./ui/input"

    type InputProps = {
        name: string
        placeholder: string
    }
    
    const ItemInput = ({name, placeholder}: InputProps) => {
      return (
        <div>
             <FormField
                control={form.control}
                name={name}
                render={({ field }) => (
                  <FormItem>
                    <FormControl>
                      <Input placeholder={placeholder} {...field} />
                    </FormControl>
                    <FormMessage />
                  </FormItem>
                )}
              />
        </div>
      )
    }
    
    export default ItemInput
```

Is there any way I can avoid repeating the "control={form.control" line every time I reuse the "ItemInput" custom component?

Comment: isn't it an important property that can be varied from a form to another? For example, in a component and you have 2 forms, passing a `control` prop should be a must. And if possible can you produce a reproducible example since it's a bit hard to imagine what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: You might be right, but I can't think of any scenario where the line "control={form.control}" would change. Can you give me an example? shadcn/ui is pretty new and I'm still learning how to use it.

Comment: sorry, that was bad wording from my side, I meant to say "it can be different from a form to another"

Comment: Actually, I just noticed that the code works even if I remove the whole "control" line altogeher, which is strange, as the shacn-ui docs tell you to include it.

Comment: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/255439/discussion-between-wise-chimpanzee-and-paulprg19       go here

Comment: I have added why? 
This works:
type InputProps = {
name: string
placeholder: string
}

const ItemInput = ({name, placeholder}: InputProps) => {
// const { control } = useFormContext()
return (
<div>
<FormField
// control={control}
name={name}
render={({ field }) => (
<FormItem>
<FormControl>
<Input placeholder={placeholder} {...field} />
</FormControl>
<FormMessage />
</FormItem>
)}
/>
</div>
)
}